# Re-positioning an Material label control

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am having an issue positioning a block of text with an HTML Label element. This element wraps up a mat-form-field input control and as the screen shot shows the label text lines up at the bottom of the input control, when it should line up in the center.
[image]

As you can see the Trader Reference [07] text is too low I need to move it up by a few pixels but everything I have tried fails.

I should mention I am trying to use Angular Material controls

Code as follows

```
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div>
  <mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="customCollapsedHeight" [expandedHeight]="customExpandedHeight">
      <mat-panel-title>
     <h4> Declaration Type</h4>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="field">
        <label class= "field-label">Decln Type [01]:
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select class="declaration-type-combobox">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let declarationType of declarationTypes" [value]="declarationType.value">
                    {{declarationType.value}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
        </label>
        <label class= "field-label">Badge Codes:
          <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select class="badge-codes-combobox">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let badge of badges" [value]="badge.code">
                  {{badge.code}} -  {{badge.name}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div>
            <label>Trader Referecne [07]:
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput>
              </mat-form-field>
            </label>
          </div>
  </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</div> <!--End wrapper-->
</div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
 .wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

/* contains a label and a value */
.field {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.field-label {
  width: 35%;
}

.field-value {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}

.field label + label /*label after another label */
 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.declaration-type-combobox {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: #673ab7 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 9px;
}

.badge-codes-combobox {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: #673ab7 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 9px;
}

.form-field {
  width: 380px;
  max-width: 380px;
  border: #673ab7 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-panel mat-option.mat-option {
  height: unset;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded {
  background: #673ab7;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: #673ab7 2px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 9px;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matInput` directive assigned to the input is definitely the cause of the issue; removing it from the input resolves the alignment. There is something in the `mat-input-element` class that is applied to the input responsible... when I remove that class from the input in dev tools the issue also goes away.

- I have overridden every style in that class and cannot seem to figure
  out what is unique to that class causing this issue... unfortunately,
  short of digging into the library source I am at a loss as to what
  the root issue is here with the `mat-input-element` class.

You could possibly explore something along these lines to disassociate your label from the `matInput` as an alternative solution.

```
<div class="field">
        <pre style="padding-top:8px; font: 400 14px/20px Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;">Trader Referecne [07]: </pre>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput>
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old issue, but in Angular 16 I figured out that the label position is determined by the width of `<div class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></div>` before the label.
You can set the width just overriding the class using `!important`.
For example I set this:

```
.mdc-notched-outline__leading {
    width: calc(40% - 8px) !important;
}
```

For this result:
[image]

The problem is, when the input is empty, the placeholder will have the same space:
[image]

[image]

But I think that using JS/TS instead of pure CSS/SCSS it will be more easy even to handle empty input.

Hope this helps!